# Is it possible to create custom directives in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Objective-C has directives like:

- @interface
- @implementation
- @end
- @protocol
- @property
- @synthesize

I think of these things like sophisticated marco or code-generators. Is it possible to create custom directives for code-generation purposes? One possible use is generating methods for CoreData.

I'm thinking not, because I've never seen anything about it, but my world isn't the world.

---

**Followup Question:**

Jonathan mentioned below that it is possible to write your own preprocessor and this begs the question of how. Currently, #define SYMBOLIC_CONSTANT 102 will replace all instances of the characters SYMBOLIC_CONSTANT with the characters 102 in the file before the files moves on to the compiler.

I know it XCode you can add a "Run Script Phase" to a Targets build process. So I could write a script to find my custom preprocess directives like '$coredata' and then have the script generate a new file that with the characters $coredata replaced with some characters of code. But from what I understand of XCode's build process you can't feed altered files into the Compiler Sources phase. The files are specified and locked by the IDE.

Has anyone done something similar? I know it's possible with external build system, but to be honest I'm not at that level of understanding. I don't know the technical details of what the Build and Run button does.

In the meantime, I'll start reading Apple's XCode Documentation...

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: I didn't say it would be remotely easy. However, something like `$coredata` is a valid C Preprocessor token (`$` can be used in symbol/macro names), so it can be used in a `#define` statement. Again, though--if you tell us your goal, we may be able to suggest an easier or better approach to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thinking is correct:  it is impossible to do this in your code. The only way to add more `@`-directives is via the compiler itself. Even if you went to all that trouble, I can almost guarantee that the syntax highlighting support for them is hard-coded into an Xcode configuration file somewhere.

Oh, and if you were considering the use a pre-processor macro, it is my understanding that the `@` character is illegal in pre-processor macros.

Edit:  I ran a test, and I am correct. Using the `@` character in a C preprocessor macro is illegal. They follow the same rule as variable names.

Comment: I didn't mention using a preprocessor macro. Re-read my answer.

Answer (score 5):

While accepted answer is right, there is a partial hacky solution to this kind of a problem, which [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc) library adopts. Consider [this code](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTScope.h), you will find the definitions like the following there:

```
#define weakify(...) \
    try {} @finally {} \
    metamacro_foreach_cxt(ext_weakify_,, __weak, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Such definition allows using `weakify` keyword in the following form:

```
id foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
id bar = [[NSObject alloc] init];

@weakify(foo, bar);
```

---

The author of library explains it [here](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/issues/31):

> Since the macros are intended to be used with an @ preceding them
>   (like @strongify(self);), the try {} soaks up the symbol so it doesn't
>   cause syntax errors.

---

**Updated later**

[From now on](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/pull/51) libextobjc uses `@autoreleasepool` to "soak up the symbol".

Comment: *sigh, great explanation with horrible hack-ory

Answer (score 3):

You mean within the bounds of Objective-C? No, as it has no way to recognize your new keywords. You could write a preprocessor to detect `@whatever` and convert it to code, but if you tell us what specifically you'd like to do, we may be able to suggest a more efficient or optimal approach.

Comment: The @ character is illegal in C preprocessor macros.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You gave me the idea for how to do this. Forgot that you don't need a language hook to generate code.

Comment: @Carter: I said *write a preprocessor* not *use the inbuilt one*. Not that I'd want to use code that required its own custom preprocessor. (Oh, wait, I use Objective-C every day...)

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. These are keywords built into the Objective-C language. Just because there is an `@` in front of them doesn't make them different from other keywords.