# Add keyword to Objective-C using Clang

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction, llvm, keyword, clang

How would I go about adding a relatively trivial keyword to Objective-C using the Clang compiler? For example, adding a literal `@yes` which maps to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`.

I have looked at the (excellent) source code for Clang and believe that most of the work I would need to do is in [`lib/Rewrite/RewriteObjC.cpp`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/RewriteObjC_8cpp_source.html#l02535). There is the method `RewriteObjC::RewriteObjCStringLiteral` (see previous link) which does a similar job for literal `NSString *` instances.

I ask this question as Clang is very modular and I'm not sure which `.td` (see [`tablegen`](http://llvm.org/docs/TableGenFundamentals.html)) files, `.h` files and AST visitor passes I would need to modify to achieve my goal.

Comment: Why would you want to do it? You want your code compilable by your tweaked compiler only?

Comment: @Krizz To learn more about the inner workings of Clang, that's why! It's an educational exercise :)

Comment: If you just want @yes without diving into these Clang's internals, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17837531/598057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the clang's code correctly (I'm still learning, so take caution), I think the starting point for this type of addition would be in Parser::ParseObjCAtExpression within clang/lib/Parse/ParseObjc.cpp.

One thing to note is that the Parser class is implemented in several files (seemingly separated by input language), but is declared entirely in clang/include/Parser.h.

Parser has many methods following the pattern of ParseObjCAt, e.g.,
ParseObjCAtExpression
ParseObjCAtStatement
ParseObjCAtDirectives
etc..

Specifically, line 1779 of ParseObjc.cpp appears to be where the parser detects an Objective-C string literal in the form of @"foo". However, it also calls ParsePostfixExpressionSuffix which I don't fully understand yet. I haven't figured out how it knows to parse a string literal (vs. an @synchronize, for example).

```
ExprResult Parser::ParseObjCAtExpression(SourceLocation AtLoc) {
...
        return ParsePostfixExpressionSuffix(ParseObjCStringLiteral(AtLoc));
...
}
```

If you haven't yet, visit clang's ["Getting Started"](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) page to get started with compiling.